# SSIS - Execute SQL Task - Foreach Loop Container

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I try new project SSIS and i have an error

> Exception deserializing the package "The package failed to load due to error 0xC0011008 "Error loading from XML. No further detailed error information can be specified for this problem because no Events object was passed where detailed error information can be stored.". This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails.
>   ". (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)

and Foreach Container no show variables load from Executed SQL task
[SQL Server 2014, Visual studio 2015]
Please help me!

*Executed SQL Task - configuration*

[image: Executed SQL Task - configuration]

*Foreach Loop Container*

[image: Foreach Loop Container]

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of the package  flow?

Comment: Here my package sample flow [link](http://sv1.upsieutoc.com/2017/06/30/Capture3.png)

Comment: How are you storing the results from your execute SQL task? You do not show the Result set or the Result set variable in your screenshots.

Comment: There's probably something wrong with the xml that defines the package. Since it's a new package (and relatively small) i wouldn't bother trying to find the error but i would recreate it from scratch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sloved
Click properties solution and change target sql server with version running in your system.